# Combine WGL with GLUT for shapes under Windows 7 OpenGL. Missing GLUT INIT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm working with OpenGL using Win32 API. Therefore I'm using wgl (Wiggle). Everything is fine. Except if I want to use some shapes from the FREEGLUT library. For example, the teapot. I was looking at the source code of freeglut, and it seems that when I issue a 
glutSolidTeaPot(1.0); ,it exists the program because of the macro:     FREEGLUT_EXIT_IF_NOT_INITIALISED ( "glutSolidSphere" ); which calls fgerror, which has an exit(1).

Therefore, the symptom that I'm getting is obvious. When I ran the OPENGL program without any GLUT commands (like the teapot) it works great. If I use the teapot, it exits.

It is clear to me, that I'm missing initialization. The question is if I can initialize (and how) glut to be used for the shapes in my wgl context ... If this is not possible, I guess I could create the shapes myself. It is just faster to use those if possible.

All the examples that I have found so far point in how to initialize glut when you are working with glut only.

I'm using Windows 7 64, Visual Studio 2012, NVIDIA 330m , FreeGlut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While It seems that combining GLUT and WGL (Wiggle) is not possible (and rightly so), I have look at the code and it seems that this could be change to make it work. Of course, why make it work? Because of the additional utilties that GLUT (FreeGlut) has... like creating a sphere... 
A better approach is to create a modern library to do all of this... Of course, you have some of the geometry libraries outthere, but I haven't check them. 
I'm talking something more like the AUX library, but up to date.

Answer (score 3):

FreeGLUT is not intended to be used in part. It is a system for creating and managing an OpenGL rendering context. It has utilities functions, but it's primary purpose is to create and manage a window. So if you're not using FreeGLUT to create and manage OpenGL, you don't get to use it for other things too.

Comment: When looking at the code, it seems that it may be possible. Has anyone done it? If they are not using GLUT, what do they use for some of the shapes that is included in the glut library. I know there was an old AUX library, but I have also read that is not maintained and it is suggested not to use it.

Comment: When I meant, it may be possible, this may required to change so much code in FreeGlut that may  not even be worth it. I can always copy and paste what I need from there... and make some changes